# Can I use facebook app ID for multiple domains?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I mean when  Igenerate a code for my like button here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I just want to get a code and not to create a new app id for every small wordpress site.

Can I use one for all clients and their websites?

I will use ony likebox and like button no FB login etc.

If it is possible, what are the disadvantages/security problems, if there are any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the like button, then there's no need for an app.

Comment: But what about this in fb code? <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1023443546634234";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Comment: I mean this part: en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1023443546634234

Comment: @Derfder It's not required for simple plugins.